# how to use getElementById in .js which tag is in .ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

Am trying to use electron, preload, renderer with reactj and typescript.

<index.html>

```
<body>
<div id="root" />
<script src='./renderer.js'/>
</body>
```

<index.ts>

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(<App />);
```

<App.ts>

```
<div className="App">
    <header></header>
      <MainPage />
  </div>
```

<MainPage.ts>

```
<div>
  <btn id='load' />
</div>
```

<renderer.js>

```
console.log(document) ----------------------------> OK
console.log(document.getElementById('root')) ------> OK
console.log(document.getElementById('load')) ------> null
```

To use id='load' btn in renderer.js, what can I do? what am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, there is only an empty `div` in your `html` file. When `index.ts` file is executed, React DOM renders and displays the React code you have in `App.ts`. It means React DOM updates the DOM to match your React elements.

If you run `console.log(document.getElementById('load'))`, before React DOM has finished the initial render of `MainPage` component, there is no `<btn id='load' />` element in your `html` file. Hence console logs `null`.

You should wait for React DOM to render the `btn`. After `MainPage` component is mounted (meaning is added to `html` file), you can access the `btn` by using `document.getElementById('load')`.

To make sure your code is executed after `btn` with `id='load'` is mounted:

- **Using React Functional components**: call the function you want inside `useEffect` with an empty array of dependencies. [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)
- **Using React Class Components**: use `componentDidMount` method. [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- **Using Javascript**: If you do not want want your code to be called inside React, use `MutationObserver` API. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I solved with MutationObserver. So kind Thx b :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the component `mounted`, you can use it inside `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('load'))
}, [])
```

Or you can use `template ref`.

ts:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

const buttonRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(buttonRef.current)
}, [])
```

html:
Button